# Need to record project deadline in Azure DevOps - is there a way of adding a field to the project information?

Tags: azure-devops, project

We have a process with Azure DevOps that automatically creates sprints for projects. The issue with this is that we often end up creating sprints that we don't need, and there are issues around people who are unfamiliar with project management (or useless at it is perhaps more accurate) picking everything up from the previous sprint and dropping it into the next which means some projects are in danger of going on forever more.

What I'd like to do is record the project deadline so it's clear for all.  Ideally I see this being a field alongside the project description. Is that possible?  I only seem to be able to edit items like user stories and tasks, but I need this to cover project level.

Otherwise is there any other way of recording the project deadline within Azure DevOps??

Comment: Epics and Features have a target date but no software will solve a people problem.

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: Thanks - I can understand why DevOps doesn't want to get bogged down with the PM side of things but until we can introduce better ways of working we need to do something. Have gone for the first option for the suggested workaround just because of the skill level of those using DevOps currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Otherwise is there any other way of recording the project deadline
> within Azure DevOps??

Sorry but for now Azure devops doesn't have such out-of-box Project-level field.

**Workaround:**

According to your description, you could record the deadline in [Project Summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/project-vision-status?view=azure-devops#open-project-summary) so that members will see the deadline every time they open this project.

The Project Summary supports `README` file that we maintain in project repository or  `project Wiki`. The README and wiki both support adding images so that we can add `Text description` or `Image description` to display the deadline in Project Summary.

[image]
(README)

Furthermore we can use WorkItem to track the deadline. Create feature which supports Target Date field=>Create shared query to get the workitem details(Add column options=>Target date)=>Insert query into Wiki page:

[image]

[image]
(Wiki)